# How to access another IE tab with VBS?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I made a vb script that navigate inside an intranet site. There is a link on this site that, when you click on it, it opens a new tab with a semi-random address. How do I access this tab to run javascript in it?

In my script, I create an InternetExplorer.application object that is used to control my navigation until I have to click on this link mentioned earlier. Once I run some javascript to click on the link, I don't know how to make my code run on the new tab to continue my navigation. I looked up the [documentation of the IE object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx#properties) and there is a parent property so I'm guessing I'd have to find the list of IE objects inside that parent but the parent is the script itself? I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to get familiar with "Cross tab Communication". Specifically 'localStorage'. Here is a link to start with: [HTML5 Web Storage and Cross-tab communication](https://truongtx.me/2014/06/16/cross-tab-communication-using-html5-dom-storage).

When you set a value for a local storage variable in one tab you can read it in another tab (e.g. directly after document is ready) and do something depending on it's value. Or you can hook up an event and listen for changes to the variable value and run different scripts depending on it, effectively using it as a function call from one tab to another...

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname
    If window.locationname="Scripts" then window.quit
Next
```

It returns an Internet Explorer window object.

Answer (score -1):

I use Ruby for that kind of work, it is far better for working with web-based servers and clients, for control of browser windows some gems use [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) in the background. Autoit in it's turn is far more powerfull than the regular sendkey and objShell methods of vbscript. See [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/57585-automating-clicking-of-flash-object-in-internet-explorer-using-vbscript/) for an example how to use it from vbscript.